# Javascript Money Calculations (Inconsistent Results)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am currently trying to calculate fees that my service charges for sales (8%). The seller can input the amount they want to receive, or want's the buyer to pay (Like Steam does here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pwgF.png). I am currently using this code:

```
function precise_round(num, decimals) {
var t=Math.pow(10, decimals);   
 return (Math.round((num * t) + (decimals>0?1:0)*(Math.sign(num) * (10 / Math.pow(100, decimals)))) / t).toFixed(decimals);
}

   var elem = $(this);
   elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
   elem.bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function(event){
      if (elem.data('oldVal') != elem.val()) {
       elem.data('oldVal', elem.val());
       if(elem.attr("id")=="seller-gets") {
        var cur = elem.val();
        var value = cur*1.08;
        $("#buyer-pays").val(precise_round(value), 2);
       } else {
        var cur = elem.val();
        var value = cur*0.92;
        $("#seller-gets").val(precise_round(value), 2);
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

The Receive(Left) <--> Pay(Right) conversions are not consistent. (Putting the same number the left produced back into the right gives a different left).

Sorry if this is not clear enough, I can explain it a little better if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are inconsistent before you are doing two different things. Say for eg. lets take 5 as the left number.
`8% of 5 = .4`, So Right number will be 5.4
And if you put 5.4 as the right number `8% of it is .432` not .4. So the left number will be `5.4 - .432 = 4.968` and not 5.
If you want to get back the same number then you have to multiply by 1.08 for left -> right conversion and divide by 1.08 for the vice-versa.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked great in conjunction with Neli H's parseFloat function. I wish I could pick 2 answers!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, can you be sure that the values that are passed to the precise_round function are what you expect?

If not, then I think from looking at your code that you need to convert the raw values to float. I have had the same problem with values being one cent wrong, and converting to float fixed it.

```
var value = cur*1.08;
```

should be:

```
var value = parseFloat(cur)*1.08;
```

and

```
var value = cur*0.92;
```

should be:

```
var value = parseFloat(cur)*0.92;
```

After that, you can use value.toFixed(2) instead of rounding. Something to try anyway.

Comment: I am using it currently, not sure if its helping but your answer + BlackMamba's is working.